# Intermittent NullReferenceException during .NET website compilation

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, compilation, nullreferenceexception

We have a large web application written using WebForms in C# using .NET and we have a weird problem. Hoping someone can help. We have a testing environment running IIS7 and whenever we upload modified files (.aspx, .aspx.cs, .ascx, .ascx.cs etc.) we get the following exception when trying to access the modified pages - but only for about 30 seconds. Then the application runs correctly.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetWebServiceData(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, Boolean failIfNoData, Boolean pageMethods, Boolean inlineScript) +251
   System.Web.Script.Services.PageClientProxyGenerator.GetClientProxyScript(HttpContext context, IPage page, Boolean debug) +49
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterServices() +511
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +120
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +8699694
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1029
```

As you can see it appears to be a web service failing to initialise because something's null, HttpContext maybe?!

This only happens on a regular basis in this testing environment, it has happened on our local machines but only very rarely. It never happens in the production environment. I originally thought it was something to do with the AJAX control toolkit, which we're using. I can't find anything documented about it, other than a few forum topics with no replies.

Not entirely sure how I can narrow this down any further. We have a staging environment running on the **same machine** which doesn't experience the problem. I might create a new site in IIS and point that to it to see if it helps, any suggestions are welcome.

As always, thanks for your time.

Comment: Turns out that in the master page if EnablePageMethods on the Ajax Control Toolkit's ToolkitScriptManager is set to "false", the problem goes away. Must be some sort of service that's set up behind the scenes for something the script manager uses! Stopped using it for all future projects - using jQuery UI with MVC instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only occurring when you update files, it could be because of the recompilation that takes place when you do that. It might be particularly true if it's a large site. I've had similar issue that occur with a site of my own.

As to why it only occurs in certain places, I'm afraid I have no answer.